# The Local SharePoint Server Is Not Available With A Twist

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to deploy a web part on to our local Sharepoint Server.  I am doing this through a remote login to the same server that our SharePoint site collection is on.  However, I am getting "Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application Pool': Check that the local SharePoint server is not available."  This is universal on any code I try to deploy to the Server.

Normally it would just be an issue of making me a DB_Owner on the content database.  **However, the other developers are not db_owners and they can deploy just fine.**

I checked the log and found a entries that might be a clue to what is going on.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'domain\username'
CanUpgrade [SPConfigurationDatabase] failed.
IsBackwardsCompatible [SPConfigurationDatabase] failed.
```

I apologize for not posting the entire log, but company policy will not let me post the entire log.

So, does anyone know the cause of the error and how to fix it?